# VBS : appear error "Could not use <path> file already in use"

Tags: vbscript

I have an excel file that contains a pivot table . pivot table is connected with microsoft access database in which the database is updated automatically using VBS. when the user opens or refresh pivot table, vbs can not run scripts. appear error `Could not use c:\db\amwp1.accdb file already in use.

my vbs :

```
Set dbeng = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
strMdbFile = "c:\db\amwp1.accdb"
Set db = dbeng.OpenDatabase(strMdbFile)
strSql1 = "DROP TABLE table1"
strSql2 = "SELECT * INTO table1 FROM Msfile"
db.Execute(strSql1)
db.Execute(strSql2)
```

how to solve my case?

Comment: Do you have proper rights to that DB?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try error handling, e.g. as follows (undebugged code with comments):

```
On Error GoTo 0
'
Set dbeng = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
strMdbFile = "c:\db\amwp1.accdb"
  ' Enable error-handling
On Error Resume Next
Do While True
  intButton = vbOK
  Set db = dbeng.OpenDatabase(strMdbFile)
    ' No error -> OpenDatabase successful -> Exit Do..Loop
  If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Do
    ' Ask the user (on the same computer where the script runs)
  intButton = MsgBox ("Please release the pivot table" _
      , vbOKCancel + vbExclamation + vbSystemModal _
      , "Database update")
    ' Nix -> Exit Do..Loop
  If intButton = vbCancel Then Exit Do
    ' Clear all property settings of the Err object
  Err.Clear
    ' Give Excel some time to close tables properly
  Wscript.Sleep 2500
    ' Loop to open database
Loop
  ' Disable error-handling
On Error GoTo 0
If intButton <> vbOK Then
    ' Inform the user
  MsgBox ("User did not release the pivot table" _
    , vbOKOnly + vbCritical _
    , "Database update")
Else
  strSql1 = "DROP TABLE table1"
  strSql2 = "SELECT * INTO table1 FROM Msfile"
  db.Execute(strSql1)
  db.Execute(strSql2)
End If
```

The `Err` object is an intrinsic object with global scope — there is no need to create an instance of it in your code. The properties of the `Err` object are set by the generator of an error — Visual Basic, an Automation object, or the VBScript programmer.